# Neatly iterate over javascript object and get index

Tags: javascript, sql

I am trying to use parameterized SQL in a graceful way. My front and consists of the user constructing a somewhat complex query on a number of fields. I do not know how many fields the user will specify. His query arrives to me in JSON format. Here's a sketch of my attempt to receive this request and query my database. The last three lines are of greatest interest: I want to generate clean parameterized SQL, but I have to increment the number beside the $  for each additional field being queried. I need the loop index.  What is the most graceful, Javascript-elegant way of constructing this loop? (Or if there is an entirely better way to get the job done, I'd be happy to hear that also.)

```
app.post("/foo", (req,res)=>{
    const spec = JSON.parse(req.body);
    sql = `SELECT afield FROM atable WHERE `
//** THE LOOP OF INTEREST:
    for ([key, value] of spec) {
      sql += "{key} = ${index}";
    }
```

Comment: what is `value` doing? please add an example of `req.body`.

Comment: Why don't you post a more complete example of what might be in spec? I'm also wondering why you're using e.g. `colname = $1` when prepared statements would normally be of the form `colname = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Unmitigated, for almost.  Here's the working code:

```
for (const [index, [key, value]] of Object.entries(spec).entries()) { 
    if (index == 0) sql += `WHERE ${key} = $${index} ` 
    else sql += `AND ${key} = $${index} `
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
const spec = JSON.parse(req.body);
sql = `SELECT afield FROM atable WHERE `;
let index = 0;
for ([key, value] of spec) {
  sql += "{key} = ${index}";
  index++;
}
```

or

```
const spec = JSON.parse(req.body);
sql = `SELECT afield FROM atable WHERE `;
for (let index = 0; index < spec.length; index++) {
  const [key, value] = spec[index];
  sql += "{key} = ${index}";
}
```